# Join query not showing expected results

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this table here below with `Test` and `barcode` columns matching together.

[image]

Now Im trying to join the `Valo` column with `bridgeb.barcode` (which is another table) using this code here:

```
select * from bridgeb_nocheck join bridgeb on bridgeb_nocheck.valo = 
bridgeb.barcode
```

but it gives me blank results...

If I run these codes here **it will** find the value inside both tables:

`select * from bridgeb_nocheck where valo = '01025351146865';`

`select * from bridgeb where barcode = '01025351146865';`

This is the column set up:

```
Table: bridgeb
Columns:
code varchar(100) 
barcode varchar(100)

Table: bridgeb_nocheck
Columns:
valo varchar(100)
Test varchar(100) 
code varchar(100)
```

Bear in mind bridgeb will have a few barcodes that has `valo` numbers

Comment: Are you sure you are working on the same DB and don't have any other test DB which replicates the same data?

Comment: Hi, no only have one DB and only two tables

Comment: Are you sure you are not confused by `01025351146865 (Valo)` and `0102535114685 (Barcode)`? both are different actually,

Comment: No inside the bridgeb, it has that value with extra digit and without extra digit, im trying to find all values that have an end digit from `valo` inside `bridgeb.barcode`

Comment: I have also tried trimming both values

Comment: @Eduards `end digit from valo` ?

Answer (score 0):

Test and barcode columns matching together
so u should write like this:

```
select * from bridgeb_nocheck join bridgeb on bridgeb_nocheck.Test = 
bridgeb.barcode;
```

Comment: Thats not what im after, some values from `valo` are existing inside `bridgeb.barcode` but the join statament im using it shows blank results

Comment: try  INNER JOIN  instance of join !!

Answer (score 0):

All sorted now, I have extracted the data out on excel and imported it back in. Im not sure what the problem was, but it is working completely fine now. Weird problem this was..